# Ransack error in production NoMethodError (undefined method `search' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Only in production I get NoMethodError (undefined method `search' for...... ransack gem is in my gem file, and after deploying I have restarted my app on VPS.

I tried to type

```
grep ransack Gemfile.lock
```

in the root of my app on VPS, and receive

```
ransack (0.7.2)
ransack
```

On local and remote machine I'm using ruby v 2.0.0-p0

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this on my own. It was simple, just like on local development environment.

```
cap deploy:stop
```

then

```
cap bundle:install
```

after

```
cap deploy:start
```

and it works :)